# Array throws #¿NOMBRE? when working with Strings that have "-" before them

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, bigdata

I am creating a code that loads a .txt and then takes all the lines into an array, and it works, however it has some elements (298 to be exact) with "-" before them, now, keep in mind, my array has a length of 87,899. I created this method (which works with another array)

```
function depuraArray(arreglo, c) {
var arrayDepurado = [];
for (var i = arreglo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    if (arreglo[i].indexOf(c) != -1) {
        arrayDepurado[i] = arreglo[i].replace(c, '');
    } else
        arrayDepurado[i] = arreglo[i];
}
return arrayDepurado; }
```

I have this: *(Keep in mind, arrayLem is declared somewhere else)*

```
 arrayLem = depuraArray(arrayLem,'-');
```

however I still get  **#¿NOMBRE?** for the words that contain "-". I thought that my method didn't work, but I've tested it with other words and it works!

I've tried to search for the error but google sucks at it, as it ignores the **#¿?**, thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone needs more information I'll be more than happy to provide it.

Comment: who throws a spanish error?

Comment: who? as in _which_ strings are the ones throwing it? 
every String that looks like this: -word. That's why I created my method _depuraArray_ to take the "-" off the String, and the method works with other Strings, but not with my Array.

Comment: no i mean program. All browsers i know throw english errs...

Comment: I'm working on chrome, I know it's weird even for me all the errors are in english, except for this one, I don't really know why it's happening.

Comment: may search your code for "#?nombre?" ...

Comment: It was on the .txt that I was using, thanks. Although I tried to add `  if(arrayLem[i] == "#¿NOMBRE?"){
          indicesError.push(arrayLem[i]);
        }` and it didn't work.